# Apache directory listing

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu

I am unable to stop apache from creating directory listings when using the server IP address. I have tried editing the relevant site-available files as follows;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    JkMount /* default
    ServerName example.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.example.co.uk
    ServerAdmin me@example.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.co.uk/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.co.uk/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.co.uk/logs/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/example.co.uk/public_html>
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

...but the public_html folder contents are being listed if I access the server using a url of this format;

http://192.168.1.99/example.co.uk/public_html

I have also tried to amend the apache config file at /etc/apache2/apache.conf to include the following;

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

..but no joy.

I am using Tomcat, and I need my WEB-INF folder to deny access. It doesn't, and so any .class files can be downloaded.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that it will not reach your VirtualHost settings, but default virtual host settings.

You have 2 options (at least):

1, put .htaccess file to your directory for which you want to restrict listing

2, Setup you IP based virtual host with similar settings as your name-based vhosts

You said that you put

```
<Directory />
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

You should have **Location** instead of **Directory** there

Comment: Thanks rkosegi! I amended my apache.conf file as you advised and that worked. I can no longer see the directory listing.
    
I can still navigate to .class files and download them though... do you know how I can stop this, yet allow the files to execute as expected in Tomcat?
    
thanks

Comment: Hi rkosegi, I also setup an IP based virtual-host as you said, and it has fixed my other problem too. I can no longer access .class files, as the IP address redirects to another site within tomcat. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a little weird. Do you have an Apache HTTPD in front of an Apache Tomcat Server?

In this case the Apache HTTPD must not point to a directory where the Apache Tomcat files reside! The communication between both can be seen more as a proxy rather than a plugin.

We have some good experience using mod_proxy_ajp for this purpose. But if you are able to download .class files and (panic mode on) the web.xml (panic mode off) something is terribly wrong.

Comment: Hi Wemu, and thanks for your reply. I fixed the issue now using the 'virtual IP' method suggested by rkosegi. I could only access the files directly when I used the IP address of the server as the start of the url. 

"Do you have an Apache HTTPD in front of an Apache Tomcat Server?"

- I don't know! I am using Ubuntu, and I just installed the packages as per usual. How would I find this out? I am under the impression that Apache and Tomcat are separate entities, as I have to restart them separately. Isn't this normal?

Comment: Hallooo
es it is normal. Apache HTTPD is a web-server. Powerful, extensible and flexible (authentication, mods, php/perl/phyton/...) but it cannot serve as Servlet Container for Java Applications. Therefore there is Apache Tomcat. Both come from apache.org but dont mix them up - they are completely separated as apache is a foundation and not a single product.
So it is normal you need to run two processes, the webserver that will listen on Port 80 are respond to any http:// request and the tomcat servlet container which runs on a different port.

Comment: The webserver is only a proxy that redirects certain requests to the tomcat. If by accessing the web-server using the ip address brings you to the Tomcat directory I would guess the default document root points to that location, which is not ok.

Configure Apache HTTPD to point to directories that just contain public readable files. And for the location you want the tomcat to respond configure mod_proxy_ajp or mod_proxy. In this case no document root is needed.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add /* to the end?

```
<Directory /var/www/example.co.uk/public_html/*>
        Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Update:
Or try to add the  entry outside the VirtualHost directive.

Comment: thanks for answering Attila, but no joy there. It's as if the sites-available file is being ignored!